# Problem with WFDB library in C++ project (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, qt-creator, undefined-reference

I am trying to link PhysioBank data to my Qt program in Windows 7. I followed the instruction from PhysioNet website and WFDB programmer's guide to install the package in MinGW, and tried to link the library to a simple testing program as suggested in the guide (as below). However, problems show up no mater I try with either Qt creator or Dev C++.

As suggested in the guide (p. 9), I copied curl and wfdb folders and headers to the Visual C++ directory that contains "stdio.h", and include signal.c and wfdbio.c as source files. But eventually the Qt compile error message says that "inttype.h" is not found. I guessed this is because Qt uses Visual C++ compiler but not suggested gcc, and required headers are different. But when I turn to try with Dev C++, which uses gcc 4.9.2, other errors still show up, like: "undefined reference to _imp__curl_version". Is this because the compiler is still somewhat different from that used by MinGW? If my guess is right, how could my work be possibly done?

Sorry for any beginner's mistake. Thanks very much for kind reply!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wfdb/wfdb.h>

int main(void)
{
int i;
WFDB_Sample v[2];
WFDB_Siginfo s[2];
if (isigopen("100s", s,2) < 2)
exit(1);
for (i = 1; i< 10; i++){
if (getvec(v) < 0)
break;
printf("%d\t%d\n",v[0],v[1]);
}
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: ***I guessed this is because Qt uses Visual C++ compiler but not suggested gcc,*** These will be incompatible.

Comment: ***I copied curl and wfdb folders and headers to the Visual C++ directory that contains "stdio.h", and include signal.c and wfdbio.c as source files.*** You should never touch the files in these folders.

Comment: You probably need to use the Qt installer to install mingw and Qt that was built with mingw and switch your qt-creator to use the newly installed mingw. `gcc 4.9.2` is pretty old.